# SQL schema won't run with postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I want to create this table schema

```
CREATE TABLE "CreatedAt" 
(
    "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "created" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT (now()),
    "trafficData_id" int,
    "intersection_id" int
);

CREATE TABLE "Intersection" 
(
    "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "intersection_id" int,
    "site_no" int,
    "latitude" float8,
    "longitude" float8,
    "site_name" VARCHAR,
    "relationships" VARCHAR,
    "type" VARCHAR,
    "op_status" VARCHAR,
    "road_classification" VARCHAR,
    "road_geometry" VARCHAR,
    "road_layout" VARCHAR,
    "suburb" VARCHAR,
    "switch_on_date" timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE "trafficData" 
(
    "index" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "trafficData_id" int,
    "properties_id" int,
    "latest_stats" int,
    "name" VARCHAR,
    "length" int,
    "min_number_of_lanes" int8,
    "minimum_tt" int,
    "is_freeway" bool,
    "direction" VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE "PropertyReference" 
(
    "index" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "type_id" int,
    "name" VARCHAR,
    "href" VARCHAR,
    "id" int
);

CREATE TABLE "StatisticsTraffic" 
(
    "index" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "type_id" int,
    "intervalStart" timestamp,
    "travelTime" int,
    "delay" int,
    "speed" int,
    "excessDelay" int,
    "congestion" int,
    "score" int,
    "flowRestrictionScore" int,
    "averageDensity" int,
    "density" int,
    "enoughData" bool,
    "ignored" bool,
    "closed" bool
);

ALTER TABLE "Intersection" 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY ("intersection_id") REFERENCES "CreatedAt" ("intersection_id");

ALTER TABLE "trafficData" 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY ("trafficData_id") REFERENCES "CreatedAt" ("trafficData_id");

ALTER TABLE "PropertyReference" 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY ("type_id") REFERENCES "trafficData" ("properties_id");

ALTER TABLE "StatisticsTraffic" 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY ("type_id") REFERENCES "trafficData" ("latest_stats");
```

like this.

[image]

Now for some reason I'm getting this error when i try to migrate this into the database.

> error: migration failed: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "CreatedAt" in line 0: CREATE TABLE "CreatedAt" (

I think I'm not setting the primary keys or reference keys properly. However, there are clear foreign keys, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't be able to connect these tables correctly together?

The struct in golang that the json is being unmarshaled into looks like this, the table schema i'm trying to think about so that i can add different data in the future.

```
type trafficData struct {
        Href         string      `json:"href,omitempty"`
        ID           int         `json:"id,omitempty"`
        Name         string      `json:"name,omitempty"`
        PublicName   interface{} `json:"public_name,omitempty"`
        Organization struct {
            Href string `json:"href,omitempty"`
            ID   int    `json:"id,omitempty"`
        } `json:"organization,omitempty"`
        Origin struct {
            Href string `json:"href,omitempty"`
            ID   int    `json:"id,omitempty"`
        } `json:"origin,omitempty"`
        Destination struct {
            Href string `json:"href,omitempty"`
            ID   int    `json:"id,omitempty"`
        } `json:"destination,omitempty"`
        Enabled          bool        `json:"enabled,omitempty"`
        Length           int         `json:"length,omitempty"`
        MinNumberOfLanes int         `json:"min_number_of_lanes,omitempty"`
        MinimumTt        int         `json:"minimum_tt,omitempty"`
        IsFreeway        bool        `json:"is_freeway,omitempty"`
        Direction        string      `json:"direction,omitempty"`
        Coordinates      interface{} `json:"coordinates,omitempty"`
        LatestStats      struct {
            IntervalStart        time.Time `json:"interval_start,omitempty"`
            TravelTime           int       `json:"travel_time,omitempty"`
            Delay                int       `json:"delay,omitempty"`
            Speed                int       `json:"speed,omitempty"`
            ExcessDelay          int       `json:"excess_delay,omitempty"`
            Congestion           int       `json:"congestion,omitempty"`
            Score                int       `json:"score,omitempty"`
            FlowRestrictionScore int       `json:"flow_restriction_score,omitempty"`
            AverageDensity       int       `json:"average_density,omitempty"`
            Density              int       `json:"density,omitempty"`
            EnoughData           bool      `json:"enough_data,omitempty"`
            Ignored              bool      `json:"ignored,omitempty"`
            Closed               bool      `json:"closed,omitempty"`
        } `json:"latest_stats"`

        Trend                 interface{}   `json:"trend,omitempty"`
        Incidents             []interface{} `json:"incidents,omitempty"`
        LinkParams            interface{}   `json:"link_params,omitempty"`
        ExcludedSourceIDTypes interface{}   `json:"excluded_source_id_types,omitempty"`
        EmulatedTravelTime    interface{}   `json:"emulated_travel_time,omitempty"`
        ClosedOrIgnored       interface{}   `json:"closed_or_ignored,omitempty"`
    }
```

Any ideas?

###Update

This is a update, still getting errors when trying to laod the script :D

```
CREATE TABLE createdAt (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  trafficData_id int,
  intersection_id int,
);

CREATE TABLE Intersection (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  intersection_id int,
  site_no int,
  latitude float8,
  longitude float8,
  site_name VARCHAR,
  relationships VARCHAR,
  type VARCHAR,
  op_status VARCHAR,
  road_classification VARCHAR,
  road_geometry VARCHAR,
  road_layout VARCHAR,
  suburb VARCHAR,
  switch_on_date timestamp,
  CONSTRAINT fk_createdAt
      FOREIGN KEY(id) 
      REFERENCES createdAt(intersection_id)
);

CREATE TABLE trafficData (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  trafficData_id int ,
  properties_id int,
  latest_stats int ,
  name VARCHAR,
  length int,
  min_number_of_lanes int8,
  minimum_tt int,
  is_freeway bool,
  direction VARCHAR,
   CONSTRAINT fk_tdata_createdat
      FOREIGN KEY(id) 
      REFERENCES createdAt(intersection_id)
);

CREATE TABLE PropertyReference (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  type_id int,
  name VARCHAR,
  href VARCHAR,
  id int
  CONSTRAINT fk_tdata
      FOREIGN KEY(id) 
      REFERENCES trafficData(properties_id)
);

CREATE TABLE StatisticsTraffic (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  type_id int,
  intervalStart timestamp,
  travelTime int,
  delay int,
  speed int,
  excessDelay int,
  congestion int,
  score int,
  flowRestrictionScore int,
  averageDensity int,
  density int,
  enoughData bool,
  ignored bool,
  closed bool,
  CONSTRAINT fk_stats
      FOREIGN KEY(id) 
      REFERENCES trafficData(latest_stats)

);
```

Comment: Referenced fields _must_ be unique. Add `unique` constraints to the referenced columns ("CreatedAt".intersection_id, "CreatedAt"."trafficData_id", "trafficData".properties_id and "trafficData".latest_stats).

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but in modern Postgres versions, identity columns are [recommended over serial](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don't_use_serial) and you should really [avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names). They are much more trouble than they are worth it.

Comment: What is your table CreatedAt supposed to represent? So far it looks like an entity where you link an Intersection with trafficData at a certain time. Is this so? Then why are `trafficData_id` and `intersection_id` nullable in that table? Is the same table used for certain times without an intersection or trafficData reference?

Comment: At last you should stay consistent with your naming. There is a column `properties_id` in your `trafficData` table. So I'd surmise this links to a `properties` table and references its `id` or `properties_id` - whatever you call that ID. But there is no `properties` table. And do you really want to link one trafficData row to (a group of) properties or rather to one property? If the latter, than i'd expect singualr: `property_id` (which would reside in the `property` table).

Comment: As to your table `PropertyReference`: This contains an `index` as an identity column. I'd rather expect this to be called `id` or `PropertyReference_id`, because it *identifies* a row. Call your IDs IDs. This is the common naming convention in databases when using surrogate keys. Then there is a `type_id` but no `type` table. That is not good. Then there even is an `id`, but it's not the table's ID. This is misleading and hence very bad. Get this straight.

Answer (score 4):

A foreign key references one row in the parent table. For this to happen, a column in the child table links to a column in the parent table that is unique in the parent table. Thus exactly one parent row gets referenced.

The rows in the `CreatedAt` table are uniquely identified by the column `id` (the primary key). But you are trying to create foreign keys referencing the columns `intersection_id` and `trafficData_id`. These are not unique and can hence not be used as a reference.

Your tables look weird, by the way. Your table `Intersection`has a column `id` and a column `intersection_id`. Why is that? What is the difference between an intersection's ID and an intersection's intersection ID?

And shouldn't the bridge table `CreatedAt` have foreign keys to its parent tables, which are `Intersection` and `trafficData` obviously, rather than vice versa?

This looks all very wrong to me.

Comment: So added the struct for golang in above to show the data structure. I want to make it so the schema can take in different datasets in the future, hence having a created table, that links to the other tables. I also have a separate intersection dataset that sort of relates to the incoming datasets

Comment: I don't no golang. I see there is JSON involved, and JSON is not an appropriate way to represent a database, because JSON is made for tree structures, not for a net of relations. Personally, I don't like it when they try to project a database in tree structures in 3GL langauges like Java and the like, like those OR mappers usually do. That often leads to problems. I rather have the DBMS hold my data and only deal with query results in my app which are mere two dimensional tables and thus easy to deal with in any traditional programming language.

Comment: Oops, typo. That was meant to be "I don't *know* golang" of course, but I suppose you guessed that already :-)